# Twitter API streaming issue

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to invoke twitter api to retrieve the tweets containing required hashtags using below code.

```
function _sendToFirehose() {

    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: ['235092927']});

    var records = [];
    var record = {};
    var recordParams = {};
    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
       if (tweet.coordinates){
            if (tweet.coordinates !== null){ 
              console.log(JSON.stringify(tweet));
              recordParams = {
                  DeliveryStreamName: config.firehose.DeliveryStreamName,
                  Record: {
                    Data: JSON.stringify(tweet)+',\n'
                  }
              };
              firehose.putRecord(recordParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                  log.error(err);
                }
              });

          }
        }
    });
  }
```

When I run the node in the console. it just gets stuck, Like

[image]

I am unable to figure out the reason, is the reason of getting stuck is searching across the all the tweets for the account or is it an error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are searching for real-time tweets from user 235092927. If you want to search a keyword, try:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'keyword' } );
```